# copy n symbols to container

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read arbitrary number of values using std::copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250096/how-to-read-arbitrary-number-of-values-using-stdcopy)

Hello.
I'm reading nums from file. I do it with `std::copy`

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(input_file), 
       istream_iterator<int>(), 
       back_inserter(first));
```

But this function copy only whole file, although I want to copy only N symbols.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/copy_n.html)'s STL reference is quite good. The second argument needs to be the number of items you want to read.

#### Update

(After changing your initial post, which used `copy_n`)

You can use a simple loop to do what you want, as in

```
template <typename Input, typename Output>
Output copy_n (Input i, size_t N, Output o)
  {
    for (; N > 0; --N)
      {
        *o = *i;
        ++i;
        ++o;
      }
    return o;
  }
```

Comment: There is typo in first message. I use the function std::copy, not std::copy_n. But I can't use std::copy_n, because I have old compiler - Microsoft Visual C++ 2003

Comment: "This function is an SGI extension; it is not part of the C++ standard."

Comment: The OP used it originally in his first post.

Comment: It is also part of the new standard (but could be implemented on your own easily as shown) http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#algorithms

Comment: If you're reading a stream, `copy_n` might not be right anyway. Depends whether "I want to copy only N symbols" means, "I want to copy exactly N symbols", or "I want to copy as many symbols as are in the file up to a maximum of N".

Comment: @DennyCrane: Your code is flawed, what happens if the iterator reaches end before N increments have been encountered? Shouldn't you break out of the loop? should end also be passed in?

Comment: @Beh Tou Cheh: That depends on what that code promises to do. If it is *copy exactly n elements* then why should everyone adhering to that promise pay for everyone who fails to give input that has n elements in the first place. If, OTOH, the promise is *copy up to n elements*, which is, as @Steve Jessop noted, more sensible in this case, then you're right of course. This would conflict with the expectation people grew accustomed to when they see the identifier `copy_n`, so another name should then be chosen. I guess I got locked on that `copy_n` track since OP originally used `copy_n`.